# json_extract mysql doesn't work as intended when comparing string and int types

Tags: mysql, sql, json-extract

I am trying to extract the value of a key in a json and it isn't being recognized properly :

This is what I expected :

```
mysql> SET @json_ = '{"year":"2022"}';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@json_, "$.year");
+--------------------------------+
| JSON_EXTRACT(@json_, "$.year") |
+--------------------------------+
| "2022"                         |
+--------------------------------+
```

This isn't what I expected:

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@json_, "$.year") = 2022;
+---------------------------------------+
| JSON_EXTRACT(@json_, "$.year") = 2022 |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     0 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

And

```
mysql> SELECT "2022" = 2022;
+---------------+
| "2022" = 2022 |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has to do with internal conversion and when it is triggered, make this simple trick for numbers which forces the conversion

> ```
> SET @json_ = '{"year":"2022"}';
> SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@json_, "$.year") + 0 = 2022;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> | JSON_EXTRACT(@json_, "$.year") + 0 = 2022 |
> | ----------------------------------------: |
> |                                         1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f936bf38f721bb912296ed922c632f43)*

Comment: Thanks it was that easy!, it is both equal to 2022 and "2022"

Answer (score 1):

Notice the double-quotes around `"2022"` when you extract it. JSON_EXTRACT() returns a JSON value, not a string or integer. A quoted scalar string is a valid JSON value.

You can use JSON_UNQUOTE() to get the scalar value:

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@json_, "$.year")) = 2022;
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@json_, "$.year")) = 2022 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   1 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

The trick shown in nbk's answer works only for integers. Unquoting works if you are trying to extract a string value.